# Created a website and used xampp mysql to store some values in database, everything works fine on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Created a website and used xampp localhost to store some values in database, everything works fine on localhost but when hosted website on server getting an error:

```
Error : (1045) Access denied for user 'royal'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Tried:
1. Allow privileges on all tables and database.
2. Change password, user name in config.inc

Comment: " Access denied for user 'royal'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are maybe trying to use localhost logins for the remote db on your server , you have to change the database login details of the server you are hosting on rather then using logins of your xaamps' phpmyadmin !

Comment: Okay, if I am using godaddy services for hosting then I must use it's login credentials rather than my localhost?

Comment: yes godaddy will provide you the logins for their database hosting , get those and then use them in your code near database connection :)

Comment: Hey thanks I am creating the db on godaddy server itself and hope that will work.. Thank you so much for your help. If that does not work I will come here again seeking your help. :)